# Skip items in Mybatis3 mapper foreach loop

Tags: mybatis

I have a mapper for creating a table from a object.

The thing is I can't figure out how to skip an item depending on it's "pos" property

```
<update id="createTable">
        CREATE TABLE ${param1}_${param2}_${param3.id} 
            <foreach collection="param3.field" item="field" separator="," open="(" close=")">
                <!-- Skip logic here..-->
                ${field.name} varchar(${field.size})
            </foreach>
    </update>
```

I've tried some different stuff like:

```
...
<if test="${field.pos != 1}">
    ${field.name} varchar(${field.size})
</if>
...
```

But with no luck.

Comment: Why don't you just pass properly filtered params into function?

Comment: @MichałRybak I wanted to have the possibility to change mappers without recompiling my code. But it ended in by code remove unwanted fields.

Comment: try `<if test="field.pos != 1">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html), in `<if>` tags' conditions `${}` notation **shouldn't be used**.

Try `<if test="field.pos != 1">` instead of `<if test="${field.pos != 1}">`.